# JQuery - autorefresh part of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In my Django project, I have a page that displays all the instances of a particular model. I want to auto-refresh the page every few seconds, but only update the relevant part of the page.

I'll describe each part. First - I have a Django view. In its simplest form, it looks like this

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    model = Foo
    template_name = 'mylist.html'

    def get_queryset(self):                
        return list(Foo.objects.all())    # finds all my objects from DB

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        objects = self.get_queryset()
        context = super(MyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['foos'] = objects      # this gets passed to html page
        return context
```

So it finds all `Foo` objects from the database and returns it to the html.

The html page displays a table, where each entry is a row. Furthermore, there is a checkbox at the beginning of each row. Like this

```
<table id="content">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="chckHead"/></th>
            <th>UUID</th>
            <th>Attribute1</th>
            <th>Attribute2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in foos %}
        <tr id="{{ item.uuid }}">
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" class="chcktbl" />
            </td>
            <td><code>{{ item.uuid }}</code></td>
            <td>{{ item.attribute1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.attribute2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, some of the attributes of the `Foo` model may get updated in the background, so I want to somehow refresh the page periodically with new data.

I did that in javascript, like this

```
    function setup() {
        setTimeout("refreshPage();", 5000);
    }

    function refreshPage() {
      window.location = location.href;
    }


    $(document).ready(setup);
```

So every 5 seconds, JS would call `refreshPage()`, and my page gets refreshed. If the database was changed behind the scenes, my page would reflect it.

The problem with the above is that it refreshes the whole page, which includes the checkbox. So if I had already selected a checkbox, the refresh would reset it to its original state ('not checked').

So, what is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yea if you do that then javascript is not that helpful. You need to fetch all `foos` from database again using ajax and update the table content manually. It's more work but a lot better than refreshing the page, and it's the whole purpose of using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Just really high level:

The `window.location` that you're adding is going to reset the whole page. By this time you've already figured that out. What you're looking for is something could be handled by using a page partial or by using a REST endpoint and pushing it back through the template.

Here are the steps you'll want `refreshPage` to preform instead.

1. Save off any values that you think are important
2. Send an ajax request to get either the partial or json
3. Render that new information to the page
4. Put back the values from step one over the values rendered in step 3

More likely you're going to want to wait to do the refreshPage if they're currently editing the area (saves you step 1 and 4). That, may be a choice you've already voted against.

I hope that helps, it's a very non-technical answer but I'm not sure I could give you a very specific answer without knowing A LOT more about your project.